# How to use TimeZone correctly

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I have following code in Swift 4 for iOS

```
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    var datetime = Date()
    dateComponents.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    dateComponents.day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: datetime)
    dateComponents.month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: datetime)
    dateComponents.year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: datetime)
    dateComponents.hour = 12
    dateComponents.minute = 45 
    datetime = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    print(Calendar.current.timeZone)
    print(datetime)
```

and it produces this output:

Europe/Prague (current)

2017-12-26 11:45:00 +0000

whilst I expect

2017-12-26 12:45:00 +0000

due to timezone specified. What I have to do differently?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect the hour to be 21? You set the hour to 12 local time which appears to be one hour ahead of UTC time. So the result of 11 for the hour UTC is correct, not 21.

Comment: FYI - there is no reason to set the time zone to the current time zone since that is the default already.

Comment: Typo - I expect 12:45

Comment: But if I change dateComponents.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone to dateComponents.timeZone = TmeZone(abbreviation: “GMT”) then it works as I expect. So timezone plays the role

Comment: Yeah, but I suspect that's not quite what you intended either, because the `+0000` in `2017-12-26 12:45:00 +0000` means "12:45 in London/GMT", which as you know is really 13:45 in Prague. Stop worrying about what `print(datetime)` shows, because that's always going to show you the GMT representation of the `datetime`. Always use `DateFormatter` whenever you want to show a `String` representation of a `Date` object in your local time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2017-12-26 11:45:00 +0000` is showing you the date in GMT/UTC/Zulu (that's what the `+0000` means). Bottom line, 12:45pm on 26 Dec 2017 in Prague *is* 11:45 GMT.

The `description` property of a `Date` (which is what is used if you just `print` a `Date`) always returns a string shown in GMT. If you want to see it in your local timezone, you'd use a date formatter to convert a date to a string, e.g.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
print(formatter.string(from: datetime))
```

Bottom line, if you want to display the date in the user interface of your app (where you want to show it in their local time zone), always use a date formatter. Like `DateComponents`, the time zone of `DateFormatter` defaults to the current time zone.

Note, I avoided using `dateFormat` property of the `DateFormatter` because whenever showing a date string in an app UI, you want to use a localized string (the date shown in a format preferred by the end user, as specified in the Settings app). The easiest way to achieve this is use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` as shown above.